# how to call Json Method on textbox change event using jquery in asp.net mvc?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery

I want to call a JSON method on my textbox change event using jquery.

Below is how my JsonResult method looks like

```
public JsonResult GetUserName(string emailId)
{
    string UserName = "";
    var query = (from u in DbContext.Users
                 where u.User_Email.ToLower() == emailId.ToLower()
                 select u).SingleOrDefault();
    if(query!=null)
    {
        UserName = query.User_FirstName +", "+query.User_LastName;
    }
    return Json(UserName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

below is my view code

```
Email:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="txtEmail" /><br /><br />
Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="txtName" />
```

below is the jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$("#txtEmail").first().focus();

            $("#txtEmail").change(function () {
                var emailId = $(this).val();
                //$("#txtName").val(emailId);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'GetUserName',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ emailId: emailId }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != "" || data != null) {
                            $("#txtName").val(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Our system does not recognize this email. Please try again.");
                            $("#txtEmail").focus();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Note....My GetUserName JsonResult method belongs to my Default Controller.

My jquery code is successfully getting executed on change event but the GetUserName method doesn't get called...please let me know what I am missing.

Thanks,

Comment: In addition to what @nemesv said, your action method seems to be a 'HttpGet' while you are trying to make a 'POST' request from the jQuery. Change either one to support same http verb across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You url is wrong it should be like `/DefaultControllerName/GetUserName` (it doesn't matter that this is the default controller if `GetUserName` is not the default action you have to specify the contoller in the url) that's why you should always use the built in [`UrlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492942) to generate the urls in ASP.NET MVC:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@(Url.Action("GetUserName"))',
   type: 'POST',
```

With the aspx viewengine:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%: Url.Action("GetUserName") %>',
    type: 'POST'
```

Comment: i have modified the url to /Home/GetUserName and it is working fine....by the way thanks for ur comment